# Can someone explain this question in detail?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

An infusion stated to contain 0.95% w/v NaCl was diluted so that its Na content  could be determined by flame photometry. The following dilutions were carried out:

1. 10 ml of the sample was diluted to 250 ml with water.
2. 10 ml of the diluted sample was diluted to 200 ml with water.
   The sample was found to contain 0.74 mg/100 ml of Na.
   Atomic weights: Na = 23 Cl = 35.5
   Calculate:
   The % w/v of NaCl present in the infusion
   The % of stated content of NaCl.
   The concentration  in mmoles/litre of NaCl present in the infusion.

Comment: We will not make all the calculations without you trying to enter the problem. So try and start. Tell us where you find a difficulty. We will help you go ahead.

Comment: It's an example question that I have the solution to and I just want it explained better.

Comment: Better explaining without knowledge what has to be explained better is guesswork. Say explicitly in the question what you need to explain.

Comment: It was this bit of the answer: Conc. of NaCl in the injection = 370 x (58.5/23) = 941 mg/100 ml

Comment: Since you have an answer, would you answer my question?: Is infusion contains $0.94\% (w/v)$?

Comment: I didn't realize you have the answer in comment. So it is 941 mg/100 mL =0.94% and my answer is correct.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the relationship between the atomic weight and the concentration

Answer (score 1):

In flame photometry, we need to dilute the NaCl sample because the calibration is not linear at high NaCl concentration.

It is a classical dilution problem. I find it useful to remember

$$C_iV_i=C_fV_f$$

where $i$ indicates initial concentration (before dilution) and volume and $f$ indicates final concentration and volume (after dilution).

Now note that your sample concentration is in 0.95% w/v NaCl. The flame photometer only responds to Na ions in the solution. So your flame photometer results tells you how much Na is there, not NaCl.

Try to use mole ratios between

grams of Na => moles of Na

What is the relationship between moles of Na and moles of NaCl?

Once you sort this out, edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: Thanks  it's an example so I have the answer and calculations but just don't really understand the whole process in my notes.

Comment: @Amy, do you understand it now? What is specifically confusing you?

Comment: In my notes this bit Conc. of NaCl in the injection = 370 x (58.5/23) = 941 mg/100 ml

Comment: They are arriving at the answer too quickly. What I do is that I draw block diagrams of dilution on a piece of paper and label the initial concentrations and final concentration to keep track of how much volumes were transferred.

Comment: I'm not from a chemistry background so all this is very new to me.

Comment: There are plenty of videos on dilution problems. It takes a little bit practice even with chem students. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Dilution+formula